# How to make iTunes start to play the song in a playlist that was previously stopped?

Tags: windows, itunes

Scenario:

- Playing a playlist of 10 songs.
- Stopped at the 5th song.
- I restart my computer and iTunes.
- I would like to continue playing from song number 5, but iTunes always starts playing the first song in the list.

Is there a way to change this?

Winamp has this feature, everytime I launched Winamp, it always highlight the song that it stopped previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think iTunes can do this. However, from what I've gathered online, you can right-click a song (or Ctrl-A your whole library) and go to preferences and select "Remember playback position". This will make iTunes remember where you left off in a song.

Not exactly what you were looking for, but I figured I'd poke it in here just in case.

If Winamp supports this, why did you start using iTunes. I'm pretty sure Winamp has good iDevice compatibility. I've been using Winamp for years and love it. Anyhow, good luck!

Comment: To MaxMackie, really appreciate for your reply. I'm aware of the "Remember playback position", yup, it is not what what I'm looking for. :) I have iPod & iPhone, that's the only reason why I'm using iTunes. And I personally dislike having too many programs in my PC, that's why I'm looking for solution about this without using Winamp. Thanks anyways, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

This is very well hidden option:

1. Select all of your songs with CTRL-A
2. Right click on the selected items
3. In the context menu click on "Get Info"
4. Confirm that you want to edit multiple items by clicking on "Edit Items"
5. Next click on the "Options" tabs.
6. Check the second option with the playback section which says "Remember playback position".
7. Click OK

Now you have successfully made iTunes remember the playback for this particular album.
Same way you can make iTunes remember a single song. To do that you need to right that one song and follow the instruction from #2.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Play any song from your iTunes library. Choose 'Play song' and not 'Clear Songs'. When this song finishes it will pick up your playlist again. If you choose to play the first song up in your playlist from your iTunes library just delete that song from your playlist unless you want to hear it twice.